# Greyscale texture format in vulkan

Tags: vulkan

OpenGL has greyscale texture format: GL_LUMINANCE. What is equivalent of internal format in Vulkan? Or how do we specify greyscale textures in vulkan?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take any single channel formats like `VK_FORMAT_R8_UNORM` for a 8 bit grayscale, `VK_FORMAT_R16_SFLOAT` for half precision floating point grayscale or `VK_FORMAT_R32_SFLOAT` for single precision floating point grayscale.

Pick the one that's supported that suits your needs.

Comment: The answer is correct. GL_LUMINANCE has more meaning other than grayscale. which is r=g=b=a when accessing it. though it is about imageview rather than image format.

Answer (score 6):

Ratchet Freak answers the question correctly. But if you're wondering why luminance has gone, there's some rationale from Khronos [here in EXT_texture_rg](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_rg.txt) for why Luminance and Luminance-Alpha formats have been replaced in favour of Red and Red-Green formats in modern graphics APIs.

> Historically one- and two-component textures have been specified in OpenGL ES using the luminance or luminance-alpha (L/LA) formats. With the advent of programmable shaders and render-to-texture capabilities these legacy formats carry some historical artifacts which are no longer useful.
>
> For example, when sampling from such textures, the luminance values are replicated across the color components. This is no longer necessary with programmable shaders.
>
> It is also desirable to be able to render to one- and two-component format textures using capabilities such as framebuffer objects (FBO), but rendering to L/LA formats is under-specified (specifically how to map R/G/B/A values to L/A texture channels).